# Android AlarmManager turn on screen when app in foreground

Tags: android, screen, alarmmanager, turn

I am creating an alarm app and therefore I want to run my app at a specific time using AlarmManager. It should turn the screen on and disable any keylock.

Everything works fine if the app is closed or in the background. The AlarmMager calls my BroadcastReceiver and there I can start my activity. The screen goes on and I see my app.

The problem is if my app is already in the foreground with screen turned off. I can hear the sound of my app so I know that the alarm has fired but the screen does not turn on.

I have tried playing around with task and window settings but had no success. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,

The problem might be also related to the fact that I do not all window properties in the onCreate method. I do only want to turn the screen on if the app is deciding too that there is an alarm event and triggers startWakeup after onCreate.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application ...>
    <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmMan"></receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        ...
        </activity>
    </application>
```

AlarmMan.java

```
public class AlarmMan extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, FullscreenActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

FullscreenActivity.java

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    public void startWakeup() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                mainFrame.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                );
                }
                });
                }

                public void stopWakeup() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                mainFrame.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
                        );
              }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing in your `onReceive()` method could be acquiring [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

don't forget to release it though.

Comment: yes, I figured out as well that a wake lock solves the problem. But as I understood the wakelocks are deprecated and should be replaced by WindowManager.LayoutParams. Therefore I think that there is a bug in Android 5.0. I saw a similar post in german about this at: https://www.androidpit.de/forum/625157/window-flags-werden-nur-1x-beruecksichtigt

Comment: I dont think there is a bug because I guess onCreated() in your case is not called probably cause of launchMode in your manifest. Try looking at onNewIntent().

Comment: Also I dont think wakelocks are actually "depricated", dev docs says you should use it carefully, and that for most cases window flags are enough